# What is the correct behaviour for nested task constructs?

Tags: parallel-processing, compiler-errors, fortran, arm, openmp

I encountered an issue with [nested task constructs](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf) (page 137) while testing [MagIC](https://github.com/magic-sph/magic).
The application built with Intel, GNU and Arm compilers, shows inconsistent behaviours. While Intel and GNU compilers performs well, Arm compiler triggers a segmentation fault at execution time.

Here is a reduced pseudo-code that triggers the problem ([see full example for more details lines 199-308](https://github.com/magic-sph/magic/blob/master/src/updateS.f90)):

```
      !$omp parallel default(shared)
      [...]
      !$omp single
      !$omp task default(shared) &
      !$omp private(l1) &
      !$omp private(n,i)

      [...]
    
      l1=l1_value
      n=5

      do i=1,n
         !$omp task default(shared) &
         !$omp firstprivate(i)

         [...]
         
         [Accessing an array with l1 as index]
         
         !$omp end task

      end do
      !$omp taskwait
      !$omp end task
      !$omp end single
      !$omp end parallel
```

Here the value of `l1` becomes undefined in the task construct line 14 and that causes a segmentation fault when trying to access the array at execution time.

I have tested various declarations for `l1` and declaring it as `first private`, at line 15 of the example, seems to be a good fix (to get the last value of l1 inside the innermost construct).

However I still would like to understand since the documentation is unclear to me.

It says

> If a task construct is encountered during execution of an outer task, the generated task region that corresponds to this construct is not a part of the outer task region unless the generated task is an included task.

My questions are

- Does OpenMP consider the task construct line 14 as an included task of the one line 4?
- Should the value of `l1` be propagated into the task construct line 14 or should it be undefined in the original code?
- Which compiler shows the right behaviour so I can report correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have a task inside a task. The outer one only captures a variable as `private`. How about making that `firstprivate`?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout The OP has reported that `firsprivate(l1)` fixes the issue. However, this doesn't explain the issue.

Comment: In the title do you mean "imbricated" or "*included*"? I've just learnt what the first word means, and I can't find it in the document you link to.

Comment: @IanBush I wanted to describe having a task construct inside another task construct and since the concept of "*included*" task is unclear to me, I used "imbricated". I hope that clears things out.

Comment: It's just its an extremely rare word - as a well educated (PhD) native English speaker it was totally new to me. It might help your question if you find another word.

Comment: A very unusual word. At least I had a reason to search what "imbricatus", as in Gladiolus imbricatus, actually means.

Comment: "imbriqué" is a common word in french, and in this context it means "nested". I'm not fully sure that "imbricated" in english has exactly the same meaning as "imbriqué" in french.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the answer about the inner tasks being "included tasks" or not. The specification on this topic is really unclear to me.

However, you have specified the `default(shared)` clause for the inner tasks, meaning that `l1` is supposed to be (obviously) shared... The question is "shared with what?"... With the `l1` that is private to the outer task, or with the global `l1` that has not been initialized?

- If shared with the private `l1` of the outer task: this `l1` is initialized, so the shared `l1` within the inner tasks should not be undefined... Unless the outer task terminates before the inner tasks are fully executed (in which case the private `l1` would go out of scope): but this should NOT happen, thanks to the `taskwait` directive that you have inserted.
- If shared with the global `l1`: it is unitialized, thus undefined. But declaring the inner task `l1` as `firstprivate` would have then no reason to fix the issue: you would have private `l1` in the inner tasks, which would be initialized to undefined values.

Conclusion: I bet on a compiler bug for the ARM version.